# Performance degradation/site is down, guessing it's caused by PHP-7.3 FPM buffer overflow?

Tags: performance, nginx, nginx-config, fpm, php-7.3

I am having issues with performance degradation / website is not reachable. End users see 502 Bad gateway error.

The behaviour is php-fpm works fine for several hours, then site starts to work slower and slower and then site throws 502 error.
The only solution I use is to restart php -> /etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm restart.

I am also aware of these params
emergency_restart_threshold 10
emergency_restart_interval 1m
process_control_timeout 10s

Which I set earlier, but still it doesn't resole a real issue. Sometimes web server is unavailable for 5-10 minutes.

***I suspect it's caused by php-fpm buffer overflow as when web server throws 502 - php fpm is still running. But is not able to handle new requests.***

Please advice, any help is appreciated!

I use:

```
1. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1044-aws x86_64)
2. nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
3. php7.3-fpm
```

Logs and configs:

```
1. php7.3-fpm.log
https://listhub-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/php7.3-fpm-new.log.txt
I had to restart php manually due to 502 error at 30-Aug-2019 10:08:38

2. Syslog
https://listhub-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/syslog.txt

3. PHP.ini
https://listhub-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/php.ini.txt

4. PHP-FPM.conf
https://listhub-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/php-fpm.conf.txt

5. WWW.conf
https://listhub-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/www.conf.txt
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is PHP-FPM buffer overflow? Use `dmesg` to see if you had any Out of Memory conditions and adjust PHP-FPM `max_children` to ensure that it won't cause those conditions or swapping.

Comment: Thanks @DanilaVershinin!

This is the dmesg log, could you please look at, does something stand out?

https://listhub-reports.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/dmesg.txt